# Deleting folders from GridView output

Tags: powershell, gridview

I've been working with several scripts found on here and other sources trying to work up a PowerShell script to delete thousands of empty folders that end up on our system from daily forms processing. There's several simple and effective ways of doing it, but I need a way to verify and select the folders so I don't delete the handful of folders that shouldn't be deleted even when empty.

I'm using a parameter statement for `$folder` so I can either input it on the command line or it will prompt for it.  Using this command I get the gridview and if I simply echo the output it's fine. However, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the output to either `Remove-Item` or `Del -Recurse`. Using `Del` gives me:

> del : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=D' does not exist."

which seems that it's either not getting the output vs echo or it's looking for an array?

```
foreach ($folder in (dir $target -Directory -Recurse | 
    where {-not $_.GetFiles("*", "AllDirectories")} |
    Select Fullname | 
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select Folders For Deletion and Click OK"
)) {
    del $folder -Recurse -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that script block?  You need to pipe the objects through: `| Remove-Item -WhatIf` edit:nvm. You should probably define `$Folders` before the loop so it doesn't look so monstrous.

Comment: `del $folder` -> `del $folder.FullName`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - That did fix the code with the loop, good call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this will accomplish what you want.  There's no need for a `ForEach` loop here where you're already working with a pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Target -Directory -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Object { !$_.GetFiles('*','AllDirectories') } |
  Select-Object -Property 'FullName' |
  Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Select folders for deletion and click OK' |
  ForEach-Object { Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -WhatIf }
```

Comment: That's much cleaner than using the loop. Thanks!